# See Last Commands Output from the Terminal Buffer

Tags: neovim, terminal, external-command, linux, terminal-buffer

Lets say I run the external `very_long_taking_command` like this:

```
:!very_long_taking_command
```

and I get the output in this Vim Terminal where it says "`Press ENTER or type command to continue`".

When I press `ENTER` it goes away. But what if I want to see the output again? What do I do? I don't want to run the command again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution is to use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd><</kbd>.

From the Official Vim Documentation:

> If you accidentally hit <Enter> or <Space> and you want to see the displayed
> text then use g<.
> This only works when 'more' is set.

Read more: `:help g<`

---

Note: *Works in Neovim only. In gVim + Windows it only shows you the command not the output.*

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
:term very_long_taking_command
```

If your very_long_taking_command is dos command you could have to do:

```
:term cmd /c very_long_taking_dos_command
```

Remark: if it is very long and you don't want to freeze Vim you could use an asynchronous runner like [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) and do:

```
:AsyncRun very_long_taking_command
:cw
```

Popular options are:

- [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch)
- [asyncrun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim)
- [vimproc](https://github.com/shougo/vimproc.vim)

Comment: that is definitely the best way, but there was also a way which you could do after executing the command^^

Comment: I'm afraid if the command ran in a dos box or shell box the output is lost after the shell quit :-|

Comment: I am like 95% sure there was a way. I learned that years ago when I started using vim but completely forgot about it and just remembered recently. I will let you know if I find it again :)

Comment: Omg found it: `g<`. It was in one really really old `vim_notes.md` file on my backup server :DD

Comment: Nice! but for a shell command on Windows at least it do not display the output of the command, only the command itself.

Comment: Ahh good to know^^ Let me edit my answer :)

Comment: `:term` is effectively asynchronous, no? If you want to hide it, you could close the window or move it to its own tab. Also, you could use `++hidden ++open` as in `:help terminal-close`